Visual Studio 2022「すべての設定のリセット」でエラーが出る
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.10.5 で
ツール > 設定のインポートとエクスポート > すべての設定のリセット　でエラーが出る
試したこと
・VisualStudio 2022のアンインストールとイントール
状況
「設定はリセットされましたが、エラーが発生しました。
エラー 1:  '全般' [コード 5465] の設定のインポート中にエラーが発生しました。」
あるいは
「設定はリセットされましたが、エラーが発生しました。
エラー 1:  」
このエラーは同バージョンで発生させない手段ありますでしょうか？

Visual Studioの起動を「管理者として実行」して作業 すべての設定をリセットする してみるか、Visual Studio Installerで「その他」の「修復」を行ってみてはどうでしょう？ Visual Studio を修復します あるいはどうせすべての設定をリセットするなら、Visual Studio Installerでいったんアンインストールしてから再インストールするとか？ Visual Studio をアンインストールまたは削除する
